# can't sign up (error for 'object' method), can't sign in (error for 'create' method)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

when I try signing up in my local host this is the error I get:

```
NameError in Users#new
Showing /Users/alonbond/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb where line #1 raised:
undefined local variable or method `object' for #<#<Class:0x007f90a3c32d60>:0x007f90a3bf83b8>
Extracted source (around line #1):

    1: <% if object.errors.any? %>
    2:   <div id="error_explanation">
    3:     <h2>
    4:       <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>
```

this is the code for "new"

```
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
  <%= render 'fields', :f => f %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
```

My 2nd problem is when I try to sign in (I've signed up before):

```
NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
```

this is the code for 'create' method:

```
def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password])

    if user.nil?
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
      @title = "Sign in"
      render 'new'
    else 
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user
    end  
  end
```

for_for:

```
<%= form_for(:session, :url => sessions_path) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@user` for the local variable to the partial, use `flash[:error]` for the flash message.

Comment: the @user for the partial works for now, but replacing the 'object' with flash errors is to messy because more files include the 'object', and honestly and I don't know how to replace them all to working flash errors. the 'object' suppose to work. so why isn't it? thanks a lot!

Comment: @AlonWeissfeld Does your `new` method create a new user? If it doesn't, I'd expect an error in `form_for` as well, but otherwise, I don't know. What version of Rails?

Comment: Yes, 'new' creates a new user. anyways, I've posted the form_for code at the main question which appears to be fine. I'm using rails 3.0.1 and actually I've try to bump up rails to 3.1 but when I try to install it I get an error for failing the installing for "native extensions" without explanations.

Comment: UPDATE: I fixed the problem, which was no redirect from the 'users' folder <%= render 'fields', :f => f %> FIXED TO <%= render 'users/fields', :f => f %>. and then I had some typos errors through, but now everything works!

Comment: @AlonWeissfeld Cool :) But you shouldn't accept my answer, 'cuz it was wrong--create your own answer, and accept that one! Glad you worked it out.